# how to write a API in restful architecture that return some additional data

Tags: c#, rest

I am facing a problem I want to return student object from an API but in two different ways,

1. student without grades detail
2. student with gardes detail

First API I am using is to return a student without grade detail.
The endpoint for this API is
api/students/{studentId}

and the other API will return the list of the students with grades object in it.
I am confused about how to make a restful route for this problem?
I have tried
api/students/grades/{studentId}
is this the right way to return a student with his grades detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is well described in the "Use logical nesting on endpoints" section of the [Best practices for REST API design](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) article.

If you follow REST guidelines

- `/students` - should return list of all students; optionally filtering, sorting, and pagination can be added, for example, through query parameters;
- `/students/{id}` - should return basic information about a specific student;
- `/students/{id}/grades` - should return grades details for a specific student.